# Excel nested IFs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to combine several IF formulas with an IF(AND formula but struggling. I can manage Nested Ifs or an IF(AND formula but can't seem to combine them.

I want to say if L2 equals 1,3 or 4 then put 1, if L2 equals 2 and L6 is 1 then put 1 if none of these conditions apply, put 0.

This is the best I've managed

```
IF(L2={1,3,4,5},1,0,IF(AND(L2=2,L6=1,1,0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up the brackets:

```
IF(L2={1,3,4,5},1,0,IF(AND(L2=2,L6=1,1,0)))  # your condition
IF(L2={1,3,4,5},1,0,IF(AND(L2=2,L6=1),1,0))  # fixed condition
```

so you were missing the arguments to `IF`.

Also the first OR condition seems wrong, the the whole second `IF` should be in the `ELSE` part of the firs if:

```
IF(L2={1,3,4,5},1,IF(AND(L2=2,L6=1),1,0))
```

Also the part `L2={1,3,4,5}` is not a valid condition and should be replaced by something different, for example `OR` condition:

```
IF(OR(L2=1,L2=3,L2=4,L=5);1;IF(AND(L2=2;L6=1);1;0))
```